# Outlook 2013 Custom Fields - Embed data in "content"

Tags: vbscript, calendar, outlook, custom-controls, office365

I've just discovered that you can make custom forms in Outlook 2013. Now, we currently use two calendar apps, one which is very specific to our business needs and the other is Outlook 2013 (Office365). We currently sync some events, but not all, since the extra events don't have any place in Outlook as they'd be missing a tonne of relevant data, or it just wouldn't be readable.

Is it possible to "embed" this data in the content of a custom form, then read this using VBScript/some other method? If we could do this, then it would make the readability of the bespoke events in our business calendar a lot easier. I cannot find anything on this online (probably because I don't know exactly what to search for). I do not need the outlook version to update the business calendar.

For example, data might look like this

`{"primaryGroup":"01-XUA-AL","eventName":"Customer Request 192"}`

Answer (score 0):

Outlook custom forms is a relatively old technology. I'd recommend using the Outlook form regions for customizing the UI. See [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

You may embed a custom information into user properties. They are preserved if the corresponding properties are defined on the recipient Inbox. See [Changes to custom properties in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/907985?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information.